# Retrieving parent page grid with javascript

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have a parent page that opens a modal dialog page. Modal dialog page has jabvascript in the header that retrieves grid information from parent page using the following javascript:

```
var ig$ = apex.region("pg_2_ig_grid").widget(),
    view = ig$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");
```

`apex.region("pg_2_ig_grid")` returns null so I get an error. Not sure why this is happening. I also tried adding javascript to shared components but getting the same error. How can I access a grid on page 2 from modal dialog page 3?

Comment: I have not tested it, but try to put "parent" at the beginning of each javascript statement that should do something on the parent page. "parent.apex.region..."

Comment: Bingo! Please post this as an answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested it, but try to put "parent" at the beginning of each javascript statement that should do something on the parent page. "parent.apex.region..."

Comment: could you please take a look at my other two open questions?